# How to post comment meta data with Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm tring to post meta data with Wordpress Rest API (/wp-json/wp/v2/comments), but i'm getting this 401 error

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_update","message":"Sorry, you do not have permission to edit the custom field stars.","data":{"key":"stars","status":401}}
```

My Vue.js methods to post

```
submitForm: function() {
    axios.post('https://dev.lesdeuxvagues.com/admin-ceformed/wp-json/wp/v2/comments', {
      post: 26,
      author_name: this.nom + ' '+ this.prenom,
      author_email: this.mail,
      content: this.message,
      meta:{
        stars:this.note,
      }
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

My meta registration :

```
add_action('init', function() {
register_meta('comment', 'stars', [
    'type' => 'number',
    'description' => __('Stars'),
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'auth_callback'     => '__return_true',
]);
}, 10 , 0);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You forgot to pass the ```nonce``` to the ```rest api```! Use ```wp_create_nonce("wp_rest")``` to create it and then pass it the rest api.

Comment: Thanks @Ruvee for the answer, I took a look, but I don't see how I can create a token on the Nuxt.js side with wp_create_nonce("wp_rest") on the Wordpress?

Comment: in your ```functions.php``` file, paste the following code: ```wp_localize_script("my_data_js", "myWpData", array(
  "nonce" => wp_create_nonce("wp_rest")
));```. After that you'll have access to the value on your javascript. Then send it to rest api as a header in your javascript, like so: ```setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", myWpData.nonce);```